# Create a List with a static textView

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I need your help.  My problem is that I'm trying to create a layout that have a static textView and in the bottom a List with an adapter.  I don't know how to do that. There is what I want that the layout show me:

> NameOfPerson     //The static text

- Exm1
- Exm2
- Exm3

The problem is show the list with the static text, and/or show the static text with the list.  What I have to do? I have to use fragments?

Thanks,

Comment: u need to add fotter to ur listview

Comment: "The problem is show the list with the static text, and/or show the static text with the list." -- Please be more specific on what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with that solution?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: At that moment I was starting in Android. I just read my question now and I'm like "Why I didn't know that?" Anyway, thanks for your help. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
View footerView = ((LayoutInflater) ActivityContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.footer_layout, null, false);
ListView.addFooterView(footerView);
```

Comment: By the way, `ActivityContext.getSystemService(...)` can usually be massively simplified since Activity has a getLayoutInflater()`.

Answer (score 0):

See [ListView.html.addHeaderView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View%29).

Do your ListView as you normally would, and add the extra view with `addHeaderView`.  Be sure to call `addHeaderView` before `setAdapter` though, otherwise it won't have any effect.